# Office 365: Filtering on createdDateTime for a Group's Drive

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API. I was wondering whether or not filtering was supported on the `createdDateTime` property for a group's drive.

API Call:

```
https://graph.microsoft-ppe.com/v1.0/groups/GROUP-ID-HERE/drive/root/children?$filter=createdDateTime+gt+2016-07-06T00:00:00.00Z
```

Error Message:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "invalidRequest",
>           "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": "f9be6675-5498-480c-b219-4de86592f824",
>               "date": "2016-07-13T00:06:32"
>           }
>       }
>   }

Answer (score 1):

No. Based on the test, the **List Children** API doesn't support filter the result via **createdDateTime**.

If you want Microsoft Graph to support this feature, you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).